# Starvation thread

Tags: java, multithreading

In my code as I can prevent the problem of starvation caused by the simulation method of writing with sleep ? Because if a thread is put to sleep for a long time always will never write than one that you put to sleep for a short time

The program consists of many threads that continually access the write method of the class my_file , whose instance is shared by all threads,but only one thread at a time can write to the file.

```
public class My_File {

  private boolean writing = false;

  public synchronized void write() { 
    String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println(name +" writing ");
    try{
        Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random()*3000));
    } catch( InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(name +" writing end ");
  }   
}
```

I have this problem , I have a lot of files shared by many threads , all threads that do nothing but try to write to a file in the case , writing is simulated by the method sleep , I do not really write to a file , in this situation how can I prevent starvation ?

Comment: You should edit this question as it is uninterpretable in its current form. By the way, avoid using the `synchronized` keyword, as it is usually unsafe, and, in most of the other cases, it is not neccessary, but inelegant.

Comment: What can I use instead of synchronized ? What is not clear ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem/question is as the words seem to be close to random. Instead of using `synchronized`, you could, for example wrap the logger (I assume you're using a logging framework, not your own logger implementation) within a class with a `BlockingDeque` and have a dedicated logging thread take the head of the queue and pass it to the logger. `BlockingDeque` is thread safe as it always blocks when it is full. If the logging attempt times out, just retry. Also, there are other concurrent collections or solutions.

Comment: As a last resort, you could use `synchronized`, but never synchronize on `this`; instead, you'll need to have a `private Object lock = new Object();` for this purpose.

Comment: in my case as I can implement BlockingDeque ?

Comment: I think `SynchronousQueue` would fit your purposes. Anyways, *vanOekel*'s solution might be of interest for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need a fair reentrantlock to guarantee some consistent throughput. Your case is very similar to Logback bug [268](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-268), from the bug-description:

"Simple "synchronize" lock does not guarantee order of getting lock by waiting threads, so, sometimes, "last entered" thread gets the lock, while "first entered" thread may wait for a very long time ..."

and

"I tried to replace this lock with java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock working in "fair" mode, and the situation improved greatly!"

The code changes are shown in a github [commit](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/8f4c7e3d3f495420aa7210cdc366ef434166b1bf). In pseudo-code, change this pattern:

```
class MyFileUnfair {

    private final Object writeLock = new Object();

    public void write(byte[] data) {

        synchronized(writeLock) {
            writeToFile(data); 
        }
    }

    private void writeToFile(byte[] data) {
        // write to file
    }
}
```

To this pattern:

```
class MyFileFair {

    private final ReentrantLock writeLock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public void write(byte[] data) {

        writeLock.lock();
        try {
            writeToFile(data);
        } finally {
            writeLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void writeToFile(byte[] data) {
        // write to file
    }
}
```